# Angular-moment deprecation warning

Tags: momentjs, angular-moment

The following line of code generates a the warning below:

```
 <span>{{prac.dateShown | amAdd: i : 'd' | amDateFormat:'dddd D MMM'}}</span>
```

> Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date.

Both of the following line of code do not. Does anyone know what is going on?

```
<span>{{prac.dateShown | amAdd: i : 'd'}}</span>


<span>{{prac.dateShown | amDateFormat:'dddd D MMM'}}</span>
```

`i` is a number from the array: `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,]`
`prac.dayShown`is a moment variable in my controller.

---

**Adding more code**

```
<div ng-repeat="prac in practices">

  <table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]">
        <span>{{prac.dateShown | amAdd: i : 'd' | amDateFormat:'dddd D MMM'}}</span>
      </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       [...]
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: That error should only show up when a string is parsed without either having an input format specified, or being one of the standard ISO formats.  Is it possible that `prac.dateShown` is actually a *string* and not a moment object?

Comment: Yes 100% certain. This is the declaration: `prac.dateShown = moment()`

Comment: Adding some code in case it helps... Really at a loss...

Answer (score 0):

When using `prac.dateShown` you have to make sure the type is `Date` to allow Moment.js to understand the format of the value, do something like this in your component:

```
this.prac.dateShow = new Date(YOUR_VAR);
```

then `prac.dateShow` will be a valid date